# Excluding certain packages from Maven aspectj weavedependencies

Tags: maven, package, aspectj, compile-time-weaving

Is it possible to make an exception (i.e. something to be excluded ) from AspectJ weaveDependencies?
Something like the line with capital letters below?

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <weaveDependencies>
        <weaveDependency>
          <groupId>org.agroup</groupId>
          <artifactId>to-weave</artifactId>

          ***<EXCLUDE>WE.DONT.NEED.THIS.SUB.PACKAGE </EXCLUDE>***

        </weaveDependency>

      </weaveDependencies>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
```

Comment: maybe:<excludes>
              <exclude> It did not sove my problem though..

Comment: Do you want to exclude aspects from being used, or define packages for which no weaving shall be attempted?

Comment: define packages for which no weaving shall be attempted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<excludes>
             <exclude>**/gaffer/*.java</exclude>
              <exclude>**/gaffer/**.java</exclude>
       </excludes>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question above - if you add this <excludes> block to a <weaveDependency>, you'll get a syntax error.  You can use <excludes> in the form you gave to denote packages in your source code you wish to exclude from weaving, and can even exclude unwanted transient dependencies in the <dependencies> section of your pom, but so far the AspectJ maven plugin doesn't support what this is trying to do.